# How to execute and see the result of CMD command using c in linux

Tags: c, linux, terminal, raspberry-pi

I have a binary file that matches detected faces from live video stream with a face image, I am using terminal and the command is something like:

```
./match-face --face-image image.jpg --display true
```

when I execute this command I can see the faces detected on the video stream until a face matches the face-image param.
I am trying to execute this command using C code but something is not right, I tried this:

```
execl("/bin/match-face", "-face-image", "image.jpg", "-display", "true", (char*) NULL);
```

The code is compiled without any issues but executing it is doing nothing.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

execl() function returns an integer as an return code. If the return code is not 0 use errno() and strerror(errno) to determinate if there was an error and what was causing the error.

example:

```
int err=0;
err=execl("/bin/match-face", "-face-image", "image.jpg", "-display", "true",  (char*) NULL);
if( err != 0 )
{
  fprintf(stderr,"execl() failed: %s\n",strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: is -1 the return code of execl() or already translated via strerror(errno) ?

Comment: Oh I see ! You use "strerror(err)" - this is wrong ! the variable "errno" must be used ! See "man errno"